# How to get duration of an mp3 file with cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

How to get duration of an playing mp3
by cocos2d

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: You win the least work put into a question award! Congratulations. :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, that is "[[[[CDAudioManager] sharedManager] backgroundMusic] currentTime]; "